# How can I test for object keys and values equality using Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a `mapModule` where I import components and export them:

```
import ComponentName from '../components/ComponentName';

export default {
  name: ComponentName,
};
```

How can I test that `mapModule` has the correct exported keys, values and that they are not null or undefined?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

In version 23.3.0 of jest,

```
expect(string).toMatch(string)
```

expects a string.

Use:

```
const expected = { name:'component name' }
const actual = { name: 'component name', type: 'form' }
expect(actual).toMatchObject(expected)
```

result is passing test

Answer (score 271):

you can use one of those:

toEqual and toMatchObject are template matchers for objects:

```
let Obj = {name: 'component name', id: 2};
expect(oneObj).toEqual({name: 'component name'}) // false, should be exactly equal all Obj keys and values  
expect(oneObj).toMatchObject({name: 'component name'}) // true
```

or easly use toHaveProperty :

```
let Obj = {name: 'component name'};
expect(oneObj).toHaveProperty('name') // true
expect(oneObj).toHaveProperty('name', 'component name') // true
```

Comment: We have to add the property names inside an array

Comment: getting expect(...).toMatchObject is not a function error

Answer (score 95):

Keep in mind that [`.toMatchObject`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchobjectobject) checks

> "that a JavaScript object matches a subset of the properties of an object."

So **`toMatchObject` can have unintended assertions** such as:

```js
expect({ a: 1, b: 2 }).toMatchObject({ a: 1 }); // pass
```

If you do want to match an object exactly, you should use [`.toStrictEqual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tostrictequalvalue), available since [`jest 23`](https://jestjs.io/blog/2018/05/29/jest-23-blazing-fast-delightful-testing#new-matchers):

```js
expect({ a: 1, b: 2 }).toStrictEqual({ a: 1 }); // fail
```

Comment: Actually that is exactly the assertion toMatchObject is designed for. You can use toEqual if you don't want that behaviour...

Comment: This answer really should be the preferred solution for most cases.

Answer (score 13):

Just adding this tip, thought it gave even better granularity to my own tests, especially when matching against arguments to mocked services:

```
expect.objectContaining({
   url: expect.stringContaining('https://'),
})
```

Alternatively, you can use regex with `expect.stringMatching` which tests the given regex against the value. Pretty neat.

[expect.stringContaining](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectstringcontainingstring)
[expect.stringMatching](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectstringmatchingstring--regexp)

Answer (score 8):

For a single key you can check out

`expect(Boolean(obj[prop])).toBe(true | false);`

For multiple key (where all must be present) you can use,

`expect(Boolean(obj[prop1]) && Boolean(obj[prop2])).toBe(true | false);`

For multiple key (where any one must be present) you can use

`expect(Boolean(obj[prop1]) || Boolean(obj[prop2])).toBe(true | false);`

Comment: Completely incorrect. The value passed to `expect` is resolved to be a boolean, meaning you'll miss useful debug output from jest if the test ever breaks. `true | false` resolves to `1` - really, you're calling `.toBe(1)` - does that make sense? No. Do not use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to:

```
expect(JSON.stringify(object)).toBe(JSON.stringify(object))
```

This will ensure the objects are the same.

However using this:

```
expect(object).toMatchObject(object)
```

is the best option in most cases.

Comment: Hey pal, you should never try to compare JSON.stringify from an object, as object order is not guaranteed so the stringify version might change.